# How can I define "affix" displays for different sizes in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have affix to some sidebar, looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3  sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" data-spy="affix">
```

I want to tell him:

When you arrive under defined sizes:

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-3
```

I need you do disable the "data-spy" element. And when you arrive to the correct size, bring it back.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, can you show more code please? How is the size defined, then observed and acted upon?

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap col-sm and col-xs effect at 768px or less .. You can use jQuery to dynamically apply it.

Here is the code.

```
function setDataSpy() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
  var dataSpy = sidebar.attr('data-spy');

  if (windowWidth <= 768 && dataSpy != undefined) {
    sidebar.attr('data-spy', 'affix');
  } else {
    sidebar.attr('data-spy', '');
  }
}
setDataSpy();
$(window).resize(function() {
  setDataSpy();
});
```

`data-spy="affix"` is added when screen size is below 768px .. change the number as you see fit.